Extracting Text via Web Scraping: Loop with several optional start/ end strings
I would like to webscrape the text of several press statements.
The problem I'm, currently having is, to define several strings, where the scraping of the text should start/ end. For example the starting point(string) should bei either "Good afternoon welcome to our press conference." or "Ladies and gentlemen welcome to todays report.". For the end point of the web scraping I also want to provide not only one string but several options.
This is my Code so far. It only works for one specific string as start or end point. Can somone help me and explain how can I modify hat code, so that it works for mor then only one string as start/ end point. Thank you!
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(mclm)
library(tm)
url_list <- c("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/press_conference/monetary-policy-statement/2024/html/ecb.is240411~9974984b58.en.html","https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/press_conference/monetary-policy-statement/2024/html/ecb.is240307~314650bd5c.en.html")
# Function to extract text between two specific strings    
extract_text <- function(text, start_str, end_str) {
  start_pos <- grep(start_str, text)
  end_pos <- grep(end_str, text)
  if (length(start_pos) > 0 && length(end_pos) > 0) {
    text[start_pos:end_pos]
  } else {
    NA  # Return NA if start or end string not found
  }
}

# Initialize list to store extracted statements
ECBstatements <- vector("list", length(url_list))
ECB_dates <- vector("list", length(url_list))
ECB_titles<- vector("list", length(url_list))
# Loop through each URL
for (i in 1:length(url_list)) {
  myLink <- url_list[i]
  Page_ECB <- read_html(myLink)
  #Extract the title
  ECBtitles<-Page_ECB %>%html_elements(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ecb-pressContentSubtitle", " " ))]') %>% 
    html_text()
  #Extract the date
  ECBdates<-Page_ECB %>%html_elements(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ecb-publicationDate", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text2()                               
  
  # Extract the text
  text <- Page_ECB %>%
    html_nodes('p') %>%
    html_text2()
  
  # Extract text between specific strings
  start_str <- "to our press conference" # Specify your start string 
  end_str <- "questions."# Specify your end string 
  extracted_text <- extract_text(text, start_str, end_str)
  
  ECBstatements[[i]] <- extracted_text
  ECB_dates[[i]]<-ECBdates
  ECB_titles[[i]]<-ECBtitles

 
}


# Show the extracted statements
ECBstatements
ECB_dates
ECB_titles


I believe you should scrape the whole text first, and then do the cleaning, i.e., trim the text so that it starts and ends where you need.

This doesn't answer your question, but might help you to extract the text. You're using grep which takes as input a regular expression and a character vector of strings, and returns the indices of the elements which contain a max. I believe you want to use gregexec which returns the indices in the raw character arrays. Then you can extract the text with substring.

Using the {stringr} package, you can use regular expressions to capture text. This means you can use the .* expression to catch all text, with the start and end strings before and after, respectively, so that it will capture all text between both strings. On top of that, you can use the "or" symbol, |, to specify multiple strings that should match.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

start_strings_0 <- c("to our press conference", "to this press conference", "to the conference", "to our conference")
end_strings_0 <- c("questions", "question", "does anybody have a comment", "does anybody have a question", "the end", "bye")

start_strings <- paste(start_strings_0, collapse = "|")
end_strings <- paste(end_strings_0, collapse = "|")

extract_string <- paste0("(", start_strings, ")", ".*", "(", end_strings, ")")

text <- "Good afternoon welcome to our press conference, today we will talk about why Wombats are the cutest animals. Before we start, does anybody have a question? Because this will be your last chance to speak today."

text2 <- "Hello everybody to the conference. This conference will focus on the huge national issue that are mischievous raccoons roaming our streets. Any questions? None? Ok, we'll begin."

str_extract(text, extract_string)
str_extract(text2, extract_string)

